# Объединение значений в словаре по ключу Python

Tags: python, list, dict

Доброго времени суток!

Есть список словарей:

```
lst_input = [{'current_temp': 15.54,
  'time': '03:00:00',
  'date': '31-07-2020',
  'detailed_status': 'ясно',
  'feeling': 12.99,
  'humidity': 77,
  'icon': '01d',
  'max_temp': 15.54,
  'min_temp': 15.54,
  'pressure': 1010,
  'speed': 4.32,
  'status': 'Clear'},
 {'current_temp': 18.55,
  'time': '06:00:00',
  'date': '31-07-2020',
  'detailed_status': 'ясно',
  'feeling': 15.97,
  'humidity': 62,
  'icon': '01d',
  'max_temp': 18.55,
  'min_temp': 18.55,
  'pressure': 1009,
  'speed': 4.2,
  'status': 'Clear'},
 {'current_temp': 21.46,
  'time': '09:00:00',
  'date': '31-07-2020 16:00:00',
  'detailed_status': 'небольшой дождь',
  'feeling': 17.72,
  'humidity': 48,
  'icon': '10d',
  'max_temp': 21.46,
  'min_temp': 21.46,
  'pressure': 1009,
  'speed': 5.4,
  'status': 'Rain'}]
```

Как видно, это данные прогноза погоды. Здесь данные на каждые 3 часа.

Я хочу сделать список, который объединял бы в себе данные по ключам `date` - ключ родитель, `time` - ключ потомок и у `time` должны собраться остальные ключи и значения, или проще говоря вот так:

```
 lst_output = [{'date': '31-07-2020'}: [{'time': '09:00:00'}:
 {'current_temp': 21.46,
  'detailed_status': 'небольшой дождь',
  'feeling': 17.72,
  'humidity': 48,
  'icon': '10d',
  'max_temp': 21.46,
  'min_temp': 21.46,
  'pressure': 1009,
  'speed': 5.4,
  'status': 'Rain'}],
  [{'time': '12:00:00'},
 {'current_temp': 22.15,
  'detailed_status': 'небольшой дождь',
  'feeling': 17.97,
  'humidity': 42,
  'icon': '10d',
  'max_temp': 22.15,
  'min_temp': 22.15,
  'pressure': 1009,
  'speed': 5.52,
  'status': 'Rain'}]]
```

Цель (Это конечный формат, для примера):

```
Дата: 31/07/2020
Время: 03:00
Температура: 15
Влажность: 77
Статус: Дождь
Скорость ветра: 3

Время: 06:00
Температура: 17
Влажность: 61
Статус: Облачно
Скорость ветра: 1,5

Время: 09:00
Температура: 19
Влажность: 52
Статус: Облачно с прояснениями
Скорость ветра: 1
```

Я новичок в Python и буду благодарен за помощь в решении.

Comment: `lst_output` неверно задан, пробовали запускать?

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов Не понял, Вашего вопроса.

Comment: @dIm0n `lst_output` -  я создавал вручную, для понимания, поэтому мог ошибиться, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные приходят в не отсортированном виде то можно сделать

```
sorted_data = sorted(lst_input, key=lambda i: (i['date'][:10], i['time']))
```

`key=lambda i: (i['date'][:10], i['time'])` сортируем данные сперва по `date`, а затем по `time`. Так как в исходных данных ключ `date` не был одного формата то я грубо обрезал его длину - `[:10]`

```
def func(data):
    temp = set()
    for i in data:
        if i['date'][:10] not in temp:
            print(f'Дата: {i["date"][:10]}')
            temp.add(i["date"][:10])
        print(f'Время: {i["time"]}')
        print(f'Температура: {int(i["max_temp"])}')
        print(f'Влажность: {int(i["humidity"])}')
        print(f'Статус: {i["detailed_status"]}')
        print(f'Скорость ветра: {i["speed"]}\n\n')

func(sorted_data)
```

Comment: я благодарю Вас за решение, надеюсь это поможет мне в моем проекте. Исходя из кода, я ничего особо сложного не увидел. Вероятно, я слишком усложнил себе представление о решении)